# What causes data tables in Hadoop servers (and in general) to become "corrupted"?

Tags: hadoop, corruption, data-management

Today my coworker and I discovered we were unable to access a table on our Hadoop server - we couldn't perform queries on the table in Hive SQL or extract the table to our RStudio server.

Our data management person said sometimes this happens, tables become "corrupted".

Is it purely random (a stray cosmic ray?) or are there engineering or user related issues to blame for corrupted tables?

Answer (score 1):

While the question is generic, the cause of corruption can vary with different use case. Some of the reasons that I've come across are,

- Metadata of the table in Hive Metastore DB gets overwritten, edited or go missing due to any operations performed on the DB. This essentialy means, we cannot perform any query on a specific or group of tables.
- The actual data of the Hive table in HDFS gets corrupted. While the chance of hitting this very low (due to replica of data in Cluster), it is still possible if a 128 MB block of the table's file gets corrupted, then the data can't be read. This will result in partial or no data returned by the query. This can be hardware specific.